# KATA problem: square-into-squares-protect-trees

Tags: python, algorithm

I couldn't solve the following problem myself, so I searched and found an working algorithm. Could someone please explain to me the thought process, math or whatever behind that algorithm?

kata: https://www.codewars.com/kata/square-into-squares-protect-trees/train/python

algorithm (https://github.com/Peter-Liang/CodeWars-Python/blob/master/solutions/Square_into_Squares_Protect_trees.py):

```
def decompose(n):
    goal = 0
    result = [n]
    while result:
        current = result.pop()
        goal += current ** 2
        for i in range(current - 1, 0, -1):
            if goal - (i ** 2) >= 0:
                goal -= i ** 2
                result.append(i)
                if goal == 0:
                    result.sort()
                    return result
    return None
```

> edit: I'm new to Python and had some trouble understanding the code. It's clear to me now.

Comment: Have you considered signing into github to get the author's email and sending a query to him?  Why ask other people to explain his logic, when you could get the information from the primary source?  Outside of that, try tracing through the code on paper, or the python interactive shell.  See how the variables behave, and see if you can deduce your own answers to this question.

Comment: Because I think lots of people here are smarter than me (and as smart as him) and someone probably knows that logic and where It comes from. The guy is chinese, I'll ask him if no one helps me here.

Answer (score 4):

Let's let the program explain itself:

```py
def decompose(n):
    goal = 0
    print "Adding n, %s, to sequence.\n" % (n)
    result = [n]
    while result:
        current = result.pop()
        print "The last number, %s, wasn't helpful. Removing it from sequence and adding it back to `goal`" % (current)
        print "Trying lower numbers now.\n" if current - 1 > 0 else "\n"

        goal += current ** 2
        for i in range(current - 1, 0, -1):
            print "Trying %s" % (i)
            if goal - (i ** 2) >= 0:
                goal -= i ** 2
                result.append(i)
                "This number, %s, might work. Goal is not below zero. Adding it to sequence and subtracting from `goal`." % (i)
                if goal == 0:
                    result.sort()
                    print "\nFound result, %s." % (result)
                    return result
            else:
              print "This number, %s, is too big here. Continuing." % (i)
    return None
```

Produces:

```
> decompose(10)

Adding n, 10, to sequence.

The last number, 10, wasn't helpful. Removing it from sequence and adding it back to `goal`
Trying lower numbers now.

Trying 9
Trying 8
This number, 8, is too big here. Continuing.
Trying 7
This number, 7, is too big here. Continuing.
Trying 6
This number, 6, is too big here. Continuing.
Trying 5
This number, 5, is too big here. Continuing.
Trying 4
Trying 3
This number, 3, is too big here. Continuing.
Trying 2
This number, 2, is too big here. Continuing.
Trying 1
The last number, 1, wasn't helpful. Removing it from sequence and adding it back to `goal`


The last number, 4, wasn't helpful. Removing it from sequence and adding it back to `goal`
Trying lower numbers now.

Trying 3
Trying 2
Trying 1
The last number, 1, wasn't helpful. Removing it from sequence and adding it back to `goal`


The last number, 2, wasn't helpful. Removing it from sequence and adding it back to `goal`
Trying lower numbers now.

Trying 1
The last number, 1, wasn't helpful. Removing it from sequence and adding it back to `goal`


The last number, 3, wasn't helpful. Removing it from sequence and adding it back to `goal`
Trying lower numbers now.

Trying 2
Trying 1
The last number, 1, wasn't helpful. Removing it from sequence and adding it back to `goal`


The last number, 2, wasn't helpful. Removing it from sequence and adding it back to `goal`
Trying lower numbers now.

Trying 1
The last number, 1, wasn't helpful. Removing it from sequence and adding it back to `goal`


The last number, 9, wasn't helpful. Removing it from sequence and adding it back to `goal`
Trying lower numbers now.

Trying 8
Trying 7
This number, 7, is too big here. Continuing.
Trying 6

Found result, [6, 8].
=> [6, 8]
```

Comment: Thanks, mate! I'm new to Python and had some trouble understanding the code. It's clear to me now.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an optimal solution for js although perhaps being so concise is detrimental to intelligibility. But it works!

```
export class G964 {
  public static decompose = (n) => {
    let res = [n];
    while(res[0]){
      let area = n**2;
      let lim = res[res.length-1];
      res.pop();
      res.forEach(x => area -= x**2);
      for(var i=lim-1; i>0; i--){
        if(area - i**2 >= 0){
          res.push(i);
          area -= i**2;
          if(area === 0) return res.reverse();
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too was stuck on this KATA for days. Finally I gave in to searching for answer, and I only stopped at this one. The proposed solution is very slow as the number gets larger. Let's say, I got over 10s for 123456789.

When the first result is identified, the later iterations of for loop are not going to satisfy the criteria, and the loop is going to keep on until the next fit is found. For a number as large as 123456789 the first fit is 123456788, and the next number to fit the condition is 15713. That is to say, the for loop wasted time (& resource) for 123441075 iterations.

The best way to avoid this, I assumed, would be to arrive at the best fit mathematically. And I would arrive there by flooring the root of the difference (goal in given case). Replacing the for loop with while, and updating the iterator with the best fit within the loop got me the best processing time.

And voila! I get a result for n = 1000000000000000000000000 (trillion trillion) immediately, 0.00059s to be specific.

```
def decompose(n):
    diff = 0
    ans = [n]
    while ans:
        i = ans.pop()
        diff += i ** 2
        i -= 1

        # the for loop is replaced by while loop
        while i>0:
            # if square of current number is way above the difference, 
            # take the floor of square root of difference as current number.
            # (my way to avoid redundant iterations)
            
            if diff - (i ** 2) < 0:
                i = int(diff ** 0.5)
            if diff - (i ** 2) >= 0:
                diff -= i ** 2
                ans.append(i)
                i -= 1
                if diff == 0:
                    ans.sort()
                    return ans
    return None
```

Thank you for your hint at the solution!